# Is it true that $E[1_A|\mathcal G]=0$ iff $E[1_A]=0$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

I think I've proved the claim, but I'm running into a disagreement with someone.

$[\Rightarrow]:$ Iterated expectations.

$[\Leftarrow]:$ $1_A$ is a nonnegative random variable with 0 mean, hence $1_A=0$ a.s. So $E[1_A|\mathcal F]=0$.

Corollary: $P(A|\mathcal G)=0$ iff $P(A)=0$.

Definitions: $1_A$ is the indicator function on $A$, $\mathcal F$ is some $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Sorry for deleting and reposting, just saw a question that looked similar but it wasn't the same

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your argumentation.

Comment: @saz thanks for confirming